# Config.get() Not Getting Configuration From File: "custom-environment-variables.json" Nodejs, JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am learning how to configure my Node.js App environment. For this  I am using [config](https://www.npmjs.com/package/config) module.

Below is my index.js file:

```
`
    const config=require('config');
    const express=require('express');
    const app=express();
    app.use(express.json()); //BUILT-IN EXPRESS MIDDLEWARE-FUNCTION

    //CONFIGURATION

    console.log('Current Working Environment:',process.env.NODE_ENV);
    console.log('Name is:', config.get('name'));
    console.log('Server is:', config.get('mail.host'));
    console.log('Password is:', config.get('mail.password'));
```

`

I set `NODE_ENV` to `production` by the power shell command: `$env:NODE_ENV="production"`.

My production.json file inside the config folder is:

```
`{
    "name":"My Productoin Environmet",
    "mail":{
        "host": "Prod-Environment" 
    }
}`
```

And custom-environment-variables.json file is:

```
`{
    "mail":{
        "passwrod":"app_password"
    }
}`
```

I set `app_password` to `12345678` by the power shell command : `$env:app_password="12345678"` 
`config.get()` is supposed to look at various sources to look for this configurations including, json files, configuration files and also environment variables. But whenever I run my app, I get the following error:

```
`throw new Error('Configuration property "' + property + '" is not defined'); Error: Configuration property "mail.password" is not defined`
```

If I remove the line : `console.log('Password is:', config.get('mail.password'));` everything goes well. Please, guide me what is the solution?

Comment: You probably misspell: 'passwrod' instead of 'password'.

Comment: @HeroQu, I am felling so embarrassed. Thank You :)

Comment: Take it easy! I do the same all the time...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Firstly you have a lot of syntactical errors for example in
custom-environment-variables.json**

```
{
    "mail":{
        "password":"app_password"
    }
}
```

Now if u need to store the password of your mail server in the environment variables

**On windows**

```
$env:app_password=12345
```

**On Linux and OSX:**

```
export app_password=12345
```

**how to run ?**
**app.js**

```
const config = require("config");
console.log("Mail Password: " + config.get("mail.password"));
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem because i didn't define an environment variable for storing the password of the mail server. So, my suggestion will be define your environment variable for storing the password using the below command line (mac) and then your code should work.

export app_password=/* the password you want to set */

[how to define an environment variable for storing the password of the mail server.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VO9Z7.png)

Answer (score 0):

While defining environment variables in command_prompt don't put space on either side of '=' sign.....

eg:

```
set app_password = 123456 -----> is wrong way
   
set app_password=123456 ----->   will work
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue in 99% of cases is in the name of the file in the config folder, storing your custom variables

Answer (score 0):

To add on: make sure your file has .json extension.